# Why does jQuery fail to call click handler once a tag has been replaced?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happens is that once you click on the legend, its content is replaced with a new legend; but then the new one does not call its click handler when you click on it!

Here's the link to js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CfkKk/2/

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="MyClass">
<legend class="MyClass">
     My Class (click on me)
</legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
legend.MyClass:hover {
cursor: pointer;
color: blue;
}
legend.MyNewClass:hover {
cursor: pointer;
color: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('legend.MyClass').click(function() {
    var fieldset = $('fieldset.MyClass');
    var legend = fieldset.find('legend');
    var newLegend = "<legend class=\"MyNewClass\"" 
        + "<h3>My New Class (click on me again)</h3>"
        + "</legend>";
    legend.replaceWith(newLegend);
});

$('legend.MyNewClass').click(function() {
    alert('this is a new class');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you are calling the click function on `.MyNewDNS` when it should be on `.MyNewClass`

Also when you add the click function the element `legend.MyNewClass` does not exist so no event handler is added.

Try and delegate a function to the parent element like so:

```
$('fieldset.MyClass').on("click", "legend.MyNewClass", function () {
    alert('this is a new class');
});
```

Comment: jquery `.delegate()` is deprecated. Developers should use `.on()` to delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you hook up the event on the replacement legend before it exists in the DOM tree.
Thus, the jQuery selector evaluates to a length of 0, i.e. nothing, so the event handler is not attached.

The following should work:

```
$('legend.MyClass').click(function() {
    var fieldset = $('fieldset.MyClass');
    var legend = fieldset.find('legend');
    var newLegend = "<legend class=\"MyNewClass\"" 
        + "<h3>My New Class (click on me again)</h3>"
        + "</legend>";
    legend.replaceWith(newLegend);

    $('legend.MyNewDNS').click(function() {
        alert('this is a new class');
    });
});
```